# Why is it that some files on my system have a modified date before their creation date?

Tags: windows

For example the date created would be: January 8th 2010 but the date modified would be: December 27th 2001. How is it possible to be modified before it's even created? I am using Windows XP.

Comment: FluxCapacitor.exe has a known issue that causes this problem.

Comment: @Adam:  Did you come back in time just to post that?

Comment: @Adam: C'mon... FluxCapacitor.exe is OK. The problem is in the file. :)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the file was last modified (elsewhere) on December 27, 2001 and copied to your current system on January 8, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The date is just a number! There are lots of ways to fake it. Lots of utilities allow you to change file dates.

If the timestamp is a very "round" value, i.e. lots of 0's, then it's likely because some software producers do this intentionally: The set the date of all files in a product to a certain value to reflect the software version.

Even more likely, it could simply be the date/time the software (and its various components) was built or otherwise created (on some other system). A file installed from an installation disk or restored from a backup will not have a brand-new creation date; rather, the software that writes it will do its darndest to reproduce the *original* creation date.